# Adding physics to SCNGeometryElement primitive

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

I'm new to SceneKit, so it's entirely possible/likely that the thing I'm trying to do isn't even the right approach. So here's my general intent:

I'm building a "tunnel" through which a player travels. This is a procedurally generate tunnel. I'm determining the location of the points that represent the mesh of my tunnel, and then connecting points together with triangles to skin it. I'm using the following method to generate my triangles:

```
func addTriangleFromPositions(scene: SCNScene, point1: SCNVector3, point2: SCNVector3, point3: SCNVector3)
{   
    let vector12 = GLKVector3Make(point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y, point1.z - point2.z)
    let vector32 = GLKVector3Make(point3.x - point2.x, point3.y - point2.y, point3.z - point2.z)
    let normalVector = SCNVector3FromGLKVector3(GLKVector3CrossProduct(vector12, vector32))


    let positions: [SCNVector3] = [point1, point2, point3]
    let normals: [SCNVector3] = [normalVector, normalVector, normalVector]
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 2, 1]
    let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: positions, count: positions.count)
    let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals, count: normals.count)
    let indexData = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(Int32) * indices.count)

    let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: .Triangles, primitiveCount: indices.count, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(Int32))
    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, normalSource], elements: [element])

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 41.0 / 256.0, green: 16.0 / 256.0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 )

    geometry.materials = [material]
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode( node )
}
```

This works fine, and my tunnel looks like a tunnel. However, when I start trying to add a PhysicsBody to my node to make it a Static body (things should be able to crash into the tunnel, but the tunnel wall doesn't move), my application starts crashing with a EXC_BAD_ADDRESS. It actually crashes after I've added the first few triangles, so I suspect there some issue that occurs when adding a few triangles this way.

So, to test this out, I create a test project and added just a single triangle, and set its PhysicsBody to a static body. It doesn't crash, but the physics body appears to be a single point at the origin, rather than taking the shape of my triangle.

So, some questions:

1. Is this a bad way, in general, to generate custom geometry? If I really want a somewhat irregular shape, and I want it to have a PhysicsBody, is there another approach than creating triangles to connect the points?
2. Any thoughts on why creating a physics body for my triangles isn't working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to note that SceneKit will create a [physics shape](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsShape_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Shape_Creation_Options_Keys) for your custom geometry. This physics shape will **not** have the same geometry as the mesh you've created, instead it defaults to building a convex hull around the outside of your mesh. My guess is that the convex hull algorithm may not work for your tunnel mesh with normals facing inwards(?). But, even if it did work you would end up with a mesh around the outside of your tunnel preventing you from flying through it.

One possible solution may be to use the [`SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsShape_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey) when creating the `SCNPhysicsShape` to specify `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron`. If taking this approach I'd also recommend breaking your tunnel into segments around its circumference and along its length.

[image: Tube segmentation]

There are a number of reasons for this; it should help rendering performance as entire segments (nodes) will be culled by SceneKit when outside the view frustum, it should help collision detection performance (SceneKit will likely do a bounding box check before checking for mesh based collision), and lastly the physics shape generation algorithm should work.

Another approach is to generate a number of geometry primitives (`SCNSphere`, `SCNBox`, etc) that represent your tunnel and created a `SCNPhysicsShape` that is comprised of multiple shapes. This is the approach I've taken to building shapes around my procedurally generated islands, each grey box is an `SCNBox`.

[image]

SceneKit will rather helpfully show all physics shapes by turning on the appropriate debug option (possibly Metal only). eg; `scenekitView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions.ShowPhysicsShapes`.

I should add, theres nothing wrong with the way you generate your SCNGeometry. There's just some considerations you need to keep in mind, especially when the mesh has a large number of triangles.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Lock. That island of yours looks great. I envisioned my tunnel being similar to that in concept. Let's say your goal was to allow a character to walk around on your island, as though every polygon was a hard surface for them to walk on. Perhaps it is computationally too expensive to create a physics body for every polygon, which was how I was trying to approach it. Instead, would you create a bunch of SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron bodies, roughly matching the curvature of some section of your island, such that the polygons themselves only closely approximated the physics body?

Comment: TBH I would *really* like a way to provide my own mesh to a `SCNPhysicsShape` much like you originally proposed. I guess the SceneKit developers wanted to reduce the possibility that you'd slow contact detection down with too many polygons. Creating a physics shape per polygon could result in a physics shape with more contact polygons than the polygon you're trying to represent. Walking over something is tough as you'd want fairly exact results. I think `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron` is your best shot, bear in mind you have little control over how it wraps your geometry.